# Python: Best practice to raise exceptions in an API

Tags: python, exception

There is some module I am writing `AbcStore` where I have to raise several exceptions such as `TypeError, AttributeError, os.error, NotImplementedError` etc

```
# example 1
if key == 'abcd':
   raise NotImplmentedError

# example 2
os.remove(path)
```

In the above two cases, First, I raised `NotImplementedError` and second automatically raises built-in error `os.error` or `WindowsError` etc..(depends).

From the Module/ API user point of view, they don't even know where this `os.remove` happens and don't understand! Is it good to do something like this

```
try:
    os.remove(path)
except os.error, e
    raise AbcStoreException(e)

class AbcStoreException(Exception):
    pass
```

or simply raise all default exceptions directly! It may be really hard to keep track of all errors an API could raise by anyone!

How does one handle such situations?

Comment: Python's built-ins and standard library provide a few hundreds of exception classes... are you sure that your use-case isn't already implemented somewhere? If the error you want to raise is already covered by an existing exception class, use that (e.g. user passed a file object instead of a string -> `TypeError`, why invent `MyAppTypeError` with the same exact meaning?). In other words: I don't think your question has a simple answer. You have to decide each specific case.

Comment: @Bakuriu please look at the question (edited). I made my point more clear

Comment: Your question is more suited to the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) SE site. It is too opinion based for SO since you are asking about API design.